# Declaring a list that contains multiple types

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, inheritance, types

I have two classes (**TypeA**, **TypeB**), all of which inherit from a base class (**BaseType**) and would like to have a list that contains an arbitrary number of each class.

I have looked around and found some answers that are close, but I can’t quite get them to work for my situation.

I have three levels of inheritance:

```
‘CoreType is used all over my program as the base for almost every other class, so I would like to avoid changing it if at all possible.
Public Class CoreType(Of T)
End Class 

Public Class BaseType(Of T)
    Inherits CoreType(Of T)
End Class

Public Class TypeA
    Inherits BaseType(Of StructA)
    Public Property SomeA() As String
End Class

Public Class TypeB
    Inherits BaseType(Of StructB)
    Public Property SomeB() As String
End Class

Public Structure StructA
End Structure

Public Structure StructB
End Structure

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a As New List(Of BaseType(Of ???))
        a.Add(New TypeA)
        a.Add(New TypeB)    

        If a.First().GetType().Name = TypeName(New StructA) Then
            Dim x As Integer = 5
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Restrictions:

- Passing the structures as the type in the inherit statements is
  required.
- Using a list of **CoreType** instead of adding the additional
  level of inheritance is not an option.

My question is: How do I declare a list that will contain both **TypeA** and **TypeB**?

I think the problem deals with the way I am trying to declare a list of **BaseType** because it needs a type passed to it*, but I can’t figure out how to pass it the generic T since it has not been declared.

There is a solution here that is close: [Single sorted c# list with different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426664/single-sorted-c-sharp-list-with-different-types) unfortunately I couldn’t figure out how to adapt that so that it would take the generic T.

*Example of what I mean by passing a Type:

```
Public Function GetStuff(Of T)() As List(Of BaseType(Of T))
End Function
```

I am able to pass T to BaseType because I have it declared earlier in the function definition: “…GetStuff(Of T)…”

Comment: So you need `Inherits BaseType(Of StructB)`, for example, to be exactly that? You can have something like `Inherits BaseType(Of StructAB)` where `StructAB` is an interface implemented by both structures?